"Code Coverage Results" Missing in Visual Studio
I'm really new to testing, just starting out. I understood there should be a tab "Code Coverage Results" which can be opened from the Test tab, or by right-clicking on a test, but it doesn't show up. Also found the key combination C+E, C - that didn't work as well.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.10.0
Doing tests using nUint, .NET 6.0
Test tab:

Right-Clicking a test:


I don't believe this native option exists in Visual Studio. I recommend using a "Run coverlet report vs2022" extension. After installation it will be available in the following path tools -> run code coverage.

That works, thanks!
To add if someone is configuring it the same way as me -> You might get these errors: https://prnt.sc/dOt6cC6uS6DB
So search Terminal and paste: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --version 5.3.6
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool)
